# How to display a full page ad in android app

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I want to display a full page ad when the user closes the app.Like when you close AppLock app or m-indicator app we get a full screen ad.Also I would like to know whether ad mob is the only way to earn money from an android app.Thanks in advance.
Note:I created the application using cordova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Cordova to create the app, using a cordova plugin is the most easiest way to display an Ad, just one or two line of javascript code.

Following plugin is recommended by Intel XDK team and Scirra Construct 2 game maker, also compatible with IBM worklight.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/adding-google-play-services-to-your-cordova-application

If use with Cordova CLI:

cordova plugin add com.google.cordova.admob

If use with Intel XDK: Project -> CORDOVA 3.X HYBRID MOBILE APP SETTINGS -> PLUGINS AND PERMISSIONS -> Third-Party Plugins -> Add a Third-Party Plugin -> Get Plugin from the Web, input:

- Name: AdMobPluginPro
- Plugin ID: com.google.cordova.admob
- [x] Plugin is located in the Apache Cordova Plugins Registry

Quick Start Example Code

Step 1: Prepare your AdMob Ad Unit Id for your banner and interstitial

`var ad_units = {
    ios : {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy'
    },
    android : {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/zzz',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/kkk'
    }
};`

// select the right Ad Id according to platform

`var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;`

Step 2: Prepare an interstitial, and show it when needed

// preppare and load ad resource in background, e.g. at begining of game level

`if(AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );`

// show the interstitial later, e.g. at end of game level

`if(AdMob) AdMob.showInterstitial();`

Answer (score 0):

Android manages the lifecycle of applications and determines whether or not to keep them running in the background or to end them to free up resources for other applications.

You can see this for yourself by running your app on your device, then exiting your main activity and attaching with DDMS to verify the process is still there.

With that said, you could do something like override the onDestroy method of your main Activity, and create and launch an interstitial ad there.

```
InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
interstitialAd.setAdListener(adListener);
AdRequest.Builder publisherAdRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
publisherAdRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
interstitialAd.loadAd(publisherAdRequestBuilder.build());
```

As far as monetizing your app using ads, if you plan on making your app available on the Google Play Store, I believe AdMob (through Google Play Services) is the required platform through which you do this.  You can use AdMob to add in other ad networks if you want.